# Word automation use DefaultLegalBlackline to open two documents to compare documents

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, automation, office-interop

I try to open by code two documents to make them visible for the user to compare the Versions (legal blackline) - editing of the document will be done in the visible document.

That's my code fragment:

```
objectoMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

//Start Word and create a new document.
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application oWord;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document oDoc;
oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
oWord.Visible = true;

oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

oWord.DefaultLegalBlackline.....
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see a class below as sample solution:

```
    using WordR = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
    namespace WordTest
    {
        class TestComparison
        {
            private void openWordForComparison(object filenameMaster, object filenameModified)
            {
                WordR.Application app = null;
                WordR.Document docMaster = null;
                WordR.Document docModified = null;
                WordR.Document docComparison = null;
                object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                //create a readonly variable of object type and assign it to false.
                object readonlyobj = false;


                //create a word application object for processing the word file.
                app = new WordR.Application();

                // Open frist document
                docMaster = app.Documents.Open(
                ref filenameMaster, ref missing, ref readonlyobj, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

                // Open second document
                docModified = app.Documents.Open(
                ref filenameModified, ref missing, ref readonlyobj, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

                // open a new document for comparison of documents
                docComparison = app.CompareDocuments(docMaster, docModified);

                // close first and second document to display comparison only
                docMaster.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
                docModified.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

                app.Visible = true;

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:

```
oDoc1 = oWord.Documents.Open(@"Word1.docx", oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);

oDoc2 = oWord.Documents.Open(@"Word2.docx", oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);

oDoc = oWord.CompareDocuments(oDoc1, oDoc2, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdCompareDestination.wdCompareDestinationOriginal, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdGranularity.wdGranularityCharLevel, true, false, true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, "", false);

oDoc2.Close(oMissing,oMissing,oMissing);
```

Is there a solution without opening first both documents and then to Close the second document not having open, because it is not needed.